# Heroku resque/clockwork 'No job defined for class'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, resque, clockwork

I am trying to run a background job on Heroku using Resque/Clockwork.

Locally, jobs are queued by Clockwork and executed by Resque as expected. On Heroku, *sometimes* it works... but most of the time Clockwork queues the job as expected, and when executed by Resque I get a failed job with the error 'No job defined for class'.

The exact error that shows up through the Resque admin panel is:

```
Worker 960f8a1b-cce9-497a-a7ab-9b40c166a600:2+1 on FEATURED_CATALOG_ITEMS_CACHE at 27 minutes ago     Retry or Remove
Class nil
Arguments nil
Exception Error
Error No job defined for class 'Workers::FeaturedCatalogItemsCacheWorker'
```

My code looks like:

**/app/models/workers/featured_catalog_items_cache_worker.rb**

```
class Workers::FeaturedCatalogItemsCacheWorker

  @queue = :featured_catalog_items_cache

  def self.perform
    p 'do work' # there is more code here but edited for brevity
  end
end
```

**/lib/clock.rb**

```
require File.expand_path('../../config/boot',        __FILE__)
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'clockwork'

module Clockwork
  every(2.minutes, 'Queueing FeaturedCatalogItemsCacheWorker job') { Resque.enqueue(Workers::FeaturedCatalogItemsCacheWorker) }
end
```

**/lib/tasks/resque.rake**

```
require 'resque/tasks'

task "resque:setup" => :environment do
ENV['QUEUE'] = '*'
end
```

**Procfile**

```
web: rackup -p $PORT
resque: env TERM_CHILD=1 bundle exec rake resque:work
clock: bundle exec clockwork lib/clock.rb
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: The problem turned out to be that there was a node instance running it's own resque, but sharing redis with rails, both of them processing '*' queues. node was picking up rails jobs and erroring with 'No job defined for class', and rails was picking up node jobs and erroring with 'wrong constant name'.

Answer (score -1):

maybe  in `/lib/clock.rb`

```
require 'Workers::FeaturedCatalogItemsCacheWorker'
```

Solution :

require './config/boot'
require './config/environment'
require 'clockwork'
require 'resque'

module Clockwork

handler do |job|
    puts "Running job : #{job}"
    Resque.enqueue(job)
  end

every(15.minutes, NewsRssReader )
end